Question regarding piecewise definition of max function
This question is in the context of the following problem
Find the piecewise definition of the function
$$f(x) = \max\{x^2, (1-x)^2, 2x(1-x)\}$$
where $0 \leq x \leq 1$
The answer to the question in my textbook is given as follows
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-x)^2 \text{ if } 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{3} \\ 2x(1-x) \text{ if } \frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{2}{3} \\ x^2 \text{ if } \frac{2}{3} \leq x < 1\end{cases}$$
They solution for the above result in my book is given by drawing the graph of the function and then obtaining the solution.
Is their an analytical way to do this, maybe using the wavy curvy method(sign scheme method).
Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to MSE. Here's how to ask a good question. Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Given that the functions involved are all continuous, in order for them to "switch positions," they must intersect. That is, if $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, $c\in (a,b)$, $\max{f,g}=f$ on $[a,c)$, and $\max{f,g}=g$ on $(c,b]$, then $f(c)=g(c)$. So we can find points of intersection (of the first two functions, the last two, and the first and last). This will partition $[0,1]$ into finitely many subintervals. We can then pick a test point within each interval and sample to see which of the three functions is biggest on that interval.

Here is one approach - start by pairing the functions and solving some inequalities:
(1) $\   \ x^{2}>(1-x)^{2}$ has solution $x>\frac{1}{2}$
(2) $\   \ x^{2}>2x(1-x)$ has solution $x<0$ or $x>\frac{2}{3}$
(3) $\   \ (1-x)^{2}>2x(1-x)$ has solution $x<\frac{1}{3}$ or $x>1$
So, for $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{3}$, we can see that $(1-x)^{2}$ is the max function.
Between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ we have $x^{2}>(1-x)^{2}$ but $2x(1-x)$ is even greater, so we can ignore this part of the domain.
For $x\geq \frac{2}{3}$ the max function is $x^{2}$.
This just leaves the region $\frac{1}{3}<x<\frac{2}{3}$ and from the three inequalities solved above, the max function in this domain is $2x(1-x)$.
Putting this all together (the choice of $<$ or $\leq$ is quite arbitrary) gives the required hybrid function.
